# Writing a method that determines if a number is divisible by 11 and returns true or false. As well as generating 100 random integers from 11 to 110

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java as you can see and I have no idea what I am doing wrong. The outcome keeps giving me numbers that are not divisible by 11 and numbers that are not in between 11 and 110 like 7 and 1. This is what I have so far:

```
package randomnumber_and_methods;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumber_And_Methods {

   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        rand();
        
    } // End main
    
    // Method Random
    public static void rand() {
        int Result;
        Random randomNumbers = new Random();
        boolean stat;
        
      
       
       for(int x = 11; x <= 110; x++)
       {
           int randomNumber = randomNumbers.nextInt(100);
           if(x % 11 == 0)
           {
               System.out.println(randomNumber + "is divisible by 11");
               stat = true;
           }
           else
           {
               System.out.println(randomNumber + "is not divisible by 11");
               stat = false;
               
           }
               
       }    
    } // End of Method
    
}
```

Comment: You need to test if `randomNumber` is divisible by 11, not `x`

Comment: Why are you using that Random number?

Comment: To expand on what others already have said: you do your check `if(x % 11 == 0)` on your variable `x` but then print the variable `randomNumber` : `System.out.println(randomNumber + "is divisible by 11");`.  Do your check on your randomNumber and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

you have to divide the task in two part:

- 1. Generating the number
- 2. Check the divisibility

  ```
  public static void rand()
  {
      int min = 11;
      int max = 110;
      Random randomNumber = new Random();
      for (int i = 0, i < 100; i++) {
          int number = randomNumber.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
          boolean state = checkDivisibility(number);
          if(state) {
              System.out.println("The number x:[" + number + "] is divisible by 11.");
          } else {
              System.out.println("The number x:[" + number + "] is not divisible by 11");
          }
      }
  }

  private static boolean checkDivisibility(int number) {
      if(number % 11 == 0) {
         return true;
      } else {
         return false;
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

write a loop which itaretes 100 times and use the method ".nextInt" with min and max to set your range.

```
 public static void rand() {
                Random randomNumbers = new Random();
                boolean stat;
                
              
                int min= 11;
                int max= 110;
                
               for(int i = 0; i <100;i++)
               {
                   int x = randomNumbers.nextInt(max-min) + min;
                   if(x % 11 == 0)
                   {
                       System.out.println(x + "is divisible by 11");
                       stat = true;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       System.out.println(x + "is not divisible by 11");
                       stat = false;
                       
                   }
                       
               
            } 
    }
```